# How to detect if a compressed image was created from an uncompressed image

Tags: image, compression

I have 2 images:
1 raw image in pgm format
1 compressed image in pgn/jpg format

Is there a tool that can detect if the compressed image was created from the raw image?

I'm using c++ in linux, but any lead on this subject will be very helpful.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you mean you want to be able to say definitively in a court of law that `image.png` was created from `image.pgm` with tool XYZ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I'm trying to write a test for my tool that compresses images in clip : converts each image from pgm image to png. so given a png image, I want to compare it to a pgm image, and I want to make sure , with high probability that the png came from the pgm

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to compare images. You can look at the:

- Absolute Error - a count of the number of pixels that differ
- Peak Absolute Error - maximum difference at any pixel
- Mean Absolute Error - average error across all pixels
- Mean Squared Error - as above but squared
- Root Mean Squared Error - square root of above
- Normalized Cross Correlation.

There is a very good summary by Anthony Thyssen [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#compare).

If we take a greyscale Lena image and compare its PGM form with PNG and JPEG, you can get a good idea of the differences with ImageMagick at the command-line, like this:

```
# Compare lossy JPEG Lena with PGM
compare -metric RMSE lena.pgm lena.jpg null:
567.167 (0.00865442)

# Compare lossless PNG Lena with PGM
compare -metric RMSE lena.pgm lena.png null:
0 (0)
```

If I now generate a JPEG Lena with lower quality and compare with the PGM again, you can see that the error/difference is larger:

```
convert lena.pgm -quality 50 lena.jpg
compare -metric RMSE lena.pgm lena.jpg null:
1110.81 (0.0169498)
```